# How add #id to Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

How generate link like `<a href="/home/index#item">text</a>` with:

`return RedirectToAction()`

`@Html.ActionLink()`

I need add **#item** for tab open on page load.
Thanx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [`proper overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) of the ActionLink helper:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText: "text", 
    actionName: "index", 
    controllerName: "home", 
    protocol: Request.Url.Scheme, 
    hostName: null, 
    fragment: "item", 
    routeValues: null, 
    htmlAttributes: null
)
```

or a shortcut if you will:

```
@Html.ActionLink("text", "index", "home", Request.Url.Scheme, null, "item", null, null)
```

and if you wanted to redirect to such an action you could use the [`GenerateUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703653%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    string url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(
        routeName: null,
        actionName: "index",
        controllerName: "home",
        protocol: null,
        hostName: null,
        fragment: "item",
        routeValues: new RouteValueDictionary(),
        routeCollection: Url.RouteCollection,
        requestContext: Url.RequestContext,
        includeImplicitMvcValues: false
    );
    return Redirect(url);
}
```